# Is there a way to implement react-router-dom to a react project using kendoui without losing style?

Tags: reactjs, kendo-ui, react-router-dom

I am having the following Kendo-UI PanelBar:

```
            <PanelBar expandMode="multiple">
                <PanelBarItem title={'Home'} />
                <PanelBarItem title={'something'} />
                <PanelBarItem title={'something1'} />
                <PanelBarItem title={'something2'} />
            </PanelBar>
```

But as soon as I add the Link react-router-dom component my PanelBarItem lost it design:

```
            <PanelBar expandMode="multiple">
                <Link to="/home"><PanelBarItem title={'Home'} /></Link>
                <PanelBarItem title={'something'} />
                <PanelBarItem title={'something1'} />
                <PanelBarItem title={'something2'} />
            </PanelBar>
```

The code is working but I want to maintain the KendoUI desing while my code keeps working.

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution:

Basically you need to create function and call it by the same PanelBar. So inside the class you create the following function:

```
 onSelect = (event) => {
    this.props.history.push(event.target.props.route);
}
```

and then asign it to the PanelBar and give it a route to each PanelBarItem:

```
<PanelBar expandMode="multiple" onSelect= {this.onSelect}>
            <PanelBarItem title={'Home'} route='/home'/>
            <PanelBarItem title={'something' route='/something} />
            <PanelBarItem title={'something1' route='/something1} />
            <PanelBarItem title={'something2' route='/something2} />
        </PanelBar>
```